# Resource manager is not starting

Tags: hadoop-yarn

While starting resource manager from Ambari its not working and services like App Timeline Server, Node Manager and Yarn client have started n status of NodeManagers is

```
Status n/a 
active / n/a 
lost / n/a 
unhealthy / n/a 
rebooted / n/a 
decommissioned


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/YARN/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 304, in <module>
    Resourcemanager().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 314, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/YARN/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 124, in start
    self.wait_for_dfs_directories_created(params.entity_groupfs_store_dir, params.entity_groupfs_active_dir)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/YARN/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 261, in wait_for_dfs_directories_created
    self.wait_for_dfs_directory_created(dir_path, ignored_dfs_dirs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/decorator.py", line 55, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/YARN/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/resourcemanager.py", line 291, in wait_for_dfs_directory_created
    raise Fail("DFS directory '" + dir_path + "' does not exist !")
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: DFS directory '/ats/done/' does not exist !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service start script is looking for hdfs path `/ats/done`, check if such path exist with proper ownership and permissions as indicated below.

```
[hdfs@vp-solr2 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls / | grep ats
drwxr-xr-x   - yarn   hadoop          0 2017-03-27 15:12 /ats

[hdfs@vp-solr2 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /ats | grep done
drwx------   - yarn hadoop          0 2017-06-19 08:33 /ats/done
```

Comment: Thank u so much i have made all the directories and it started working now